# Providing a pointer of an object to a constructor causes object to be destructed

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I'm seeing a strange behavior in one of my projects. The circumstances are as follows:

- I have an object. Let's call `Victim`, which contains a pointer variable, a constructor and destructor.
- I have another object, let's call `Perpetrator`, whose constructor accepts a `Victim` object, and copies the pointer variable to a concrete variable inside.
- I create a `Victim*`, and create the object with `new`, then supply this to `Perpetrator` via `Perpetrator(*victim)`.
- When the `Perpetrator`'s constructor finishes, `Victim`'s destructor is called and object is deleted.

The problem is the only copy of the `Victim`, which is `poor` is completely destroyed during the construction process. Tidying up the program at the end via `delete poor` will cause a double-free error.

The behavior is consistent in C++98/11, GCC 4.8.5, 7.x, and LLVM CLANG, hence it must be well defined. What is this behavior is called, and what are the semantics of it?

My theory is, since the `constructor` accepts a concrete object, it's considered copied, so it's destructed when the `constructor` / `function` is done.

Since I praise `PoC||GTFO`, here's the code:

**Clarification:** The example is written intentionally, since it's a simplified model of a much more complex, but non-leaky and well-managed data structure complex. Removing all necessary bits made it look like an horribly broken code. In the real code `Victim` is a long living data store and `Perpetrator` is an interim storage variable used for processing said data.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Victim
{
  double* pointer;

  Victim ()
  {
    this->pointer = new double(42.2);
  }

  ~Victim ()
  {
    cout << "Destructor of the Victim is called." << endl;
    delete this->pointer;
  }

};

struct Perpetrator
{
  double concrete;

  Perpetrator (Victim victim)
  {
    concrete = *(victim.pointer);
  }
};


int main ()
{
  Victim* poor = new Victim();
  Perpetrator cruel(*poor);

  cout << cruel.concrete << endl;
}
```

Sample output:

```
./destructor_test 
Destructor of the Victim is called.
42.2
```

Comment: Rule of 0/3/5 broken. `double* pointer;` should probably simply be `double value;`, so no memory management.

Comment: The example is written intentionally in this way. I wanted to show that a benign copy can destruct the object which may be planned to be used for much longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Perpetrator (Victim victim)` - is passing an object **by value**. Means it has to be (copy) constructed, and then *destructed* when the call finishes.

As a matter of fact, there is no need to use `new` at all. This:

```
int main ()
{
  Victim poor;
  Perpetrator cruel(poor);

  cout << cruel.concrete << endl;
}
```

Acts similarly. You'll see two constructions, and two destructions. The second one your original code doesn't exhibit, because your example leaks.

Comment: I knowingly modeled the example to be leaky. You cannot re-delete the Victim in my example, since it's already and completely deleted. So it doesn't leak in practice, but leaves a trail of destruction behind. So Victim doesn't duplicated in the example, which it's duplicated in a vanilla "copy by value" scenario.

Comment: @bayindirh - *"since it's already and completely deleted"* No it is not.

Comment: Yes it's. You'll get a double free error if you add a `delete poor` at the end. The only copy of the `Victim`, which is `poor` is destructed during the construction.

Comment: @bayindirh - The double delete error is because you double delete `this->pointer`. The `Victim` object itself is very much leaking.

Comment: @bayindirh You might want to try adding copy constructor to `victim` and then do `delete poor` at end and see the results.

Comment: @StoryTeller Accessing the `poor`'s double pointer after the construction will cause an read-after-free error. Actually, I modeled the code from another codebase to make it simpler, so the behavior, pointers and structures are all deliberate. I just wanted to learn whether C++'s non-discerning nature of incoming variables are expected or not. However, your answer have answered my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

pass Victim by ref:

```
struct Perpetrator
{
    double concrete;

    Perpetrator (Victim& victim)
    {
        concrete = *(victim.pointer);
    }
};
```

Victim will construct & destruct once each.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achive?

```
using namespace std;

struct Victim
{
  double* pointer;

  Victim ()
  {
    this->pointer = new double(42.2);
  }

  ~Victim ()
  {
    cout << "Destructor of the Victim is called." << endl;
    delete this->pointer;
  }
};

struct Perpetrator
{
  double concrete;

  Perpetrator (Victim *victim)
  {
    concrete = *(victim->pointer);
  }

    ~Perpetrator ()
  {
    cout << "Destructor of the Perpetrator is called." << endl;
  }
};


int main ()
{
  Victim* poor = new Victim();
  Perpetrator cruel(poor);
  cout << cruel.concrete << endl;
  delete poor;
}
```

**output:**
42.2
Destructor of the Victim is called.
Destructor of the Perpetrator is called.